# Unity: Open local file containing a space for windows

Tags: image, url, unity-game-engine

I have tried unsuccessfully to open image file that it's name contains a space.

I use the following call:

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);
```

where:

```
url = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Files\Thumbnails\sample image.png";
```

A red question mark appears instead of image.

Also a 404 error appears when print www.error.

If I use another .png file without space (sampleimage.png), it works perfectly. On Windows and Editor it works nice too.

So I tried to replace the space with %20 but an error "can't load the file" appears.

I have also tried `WWW.EscapeURL` applied on the filename ... but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use verbatim string along with `file://` prefix:

```
string filePrefix = @"file://";
string url = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Files\Thumbnails\sample image.png";
```

Comment: I try it before and retry it now and it give me the same result: www.error is 404 Not Found

Comment: This only happens when I update unity to 2017.2 and 2017.3. I try it on 2017.1 and it works fine with the space

Comment: did you try it with file:// prefix?

Comment: It works with file:// . I used it before not correctly.
Can you please edit the answer for others?